# Accessing variables with Zend_Rest_Route

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to PHP and Zend so hopefully this is an easy one...

Simply put - how do I access an id or variable with Zend_Rest_Route?

In my bootstrap I have

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $frontController-getRouter();
$restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($frontController);
$router->(addRoute('api', $restRoute));
```

Typically when I set standard routes, I get the id by putting in my controller...

```
$router->addRoute(
          'item',
          new Zend_Controller_Route_Route(
             '/item/:itemID',
                array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'manipulateItem')
                ));
```

So I need to be able to access the 'id##' from *localhost/api/id##*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID parameter in REST routes is accessible as a controller parameter named id. In your controller actions e.g. like this:

```
$id = $this->_getParam('id');
```